# Transformar puntos cardinales en latitud y longitud en java

Tags: java, geolocalización

Tengo un programa `Java` en el que uso un tipo de objeto que almacena los `puntos cardinales` de un lugar (norte, sur, este y oeste) y necesito transformarlo en `latitud` y `longitud`.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ¿Necesito alguna librería externa?

Gracias por anticipado

**UPDATE**

Recibo esta información, y a partir de ella tengo que conseguir un punto:

```
"geometry": [{"north": 74.4, "south": 32.6, "west": 26.0, "east": 42.4}]}
```

Con ellos necesito generar un `POINT (long, lat)`

**UPDATE 2**

También puedo obtener esta información en formato POLYGON:

```
areaOfInterest": "POLYGON((7.67798 45.11909,7.60176 45.06504,7.66047 45.00936,7.70476 45.06285,7.736 45.10067,7.67798 45.11909))"
```

¿Es posible a partir de ese POLYGON obtener un POINT como el siguiente?

```
  "location": "POINT(7.6567492 45.0651474)"
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir más información? ¿Cómo algún ejemplo de los datos que almacenas ahora y el código de ese objeto que los almacena?

Comment: No soy el que te ha votado negativo, pero es fácil ver el por qué: No has puesto un ejemplo de código, ni de los datos de entrada ni lo que esperas obtener. Posiblemente no te hayan puesto ningún comentario porque no eres un usuario nuevo (¡tienes ya 15 medallas!) y se espera que conozcas cómo funciona SOes

Comment: Gracias, actualizo la pregunta. A veces uno no sabe cómo empezar a preguntar, ni si da información de más. Pensé que la pregunta estaba bastante clara. Pero ya la he actualizado con lo que recibo y lo que necesito generar

Comment: Ya he admitido el error. Mea culpa haber estado leyendo en SoF sobre el tema, perguntas supervaloradas con la misma o menos información que la mía (por ejemploi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313618/convert-latitude-and-longitude-to-northing-and-easting-in-java?rq=1) pero que vamos, que a mi lo que me interesa es resolver mi problema.

Comment: :). Recibo un JSON con una localización, que es la que he mostrado. A partir de ella, tengo que generar un punto (latitud y longitud) para enviarlo de nuevo a un servicio externo.

Comment: No se si tengo que calcular el centro del polígono que representan esas coordenadas y usar ese centro como localización.

Comment: Lo pregunto ahora mismo a la gente que me envía los datos. Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ¿cómo puede una coordenada tener las cuatro componentes (norte, sur, este, oeste)? Normalmente norte-sur y este-oeste son mutuamente excluyentes. Imagina que te envío a una biblioteca y te digo "*el libro que quiero está en la librería principal en 3m a la derecha, 6m a la izquierda, 40cm hacia abajo y 120cm hacia arriba*" ¿sabrías localizar el libro?

Comment: Es un polígono que delimita un área. Lo que necesito saber es cómo generar el punto medio de ese polígono y transformarlo en latitud-longitud

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con nueva información de datos que me pueden llegar

Comment: Pues evidentemente estaba equivocado. La respuesta de @JoseHermosillaRodrigo parece ser lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un **BBOX** o [`Bounding Box`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box), que se representa formalmente mediante una lista de la siguiente forma:

```
[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
```

Sacar el punto medio es algo trivial:

```js
var bbox = {"north": 74.4, "south": 32.6, "west": 26.0, "east": 42.4};

var { north: ymax, south: ymin, west: xmin, east: xmax } = bbox;

var puntoMedio = [xmin + (xmax-xmin)/2, ymin + (ymax - ymin)/2];

var featurebbox = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([
      [
        [xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymin],
        [xmax, ymax], [xmin, ymax], [xmin, ymin]
      ]
    ])
});

var featurepm = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(puntoMedio)
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});

layer.getSource().addFeature(featurebbox);
layer.getSource().addFeature(featurepm);

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    zoom: 2
  })
});

map.addLayer(layer)
```

```css
#map, html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.4.2/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

PD: Ya que veo que usas Java y que estás recibiendo representaciones de la geometría en formato WKT, quizás te  interese [`JTS`](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) para hacer el trabajo más fácil y llevadero.

Comment: Desconocía totalmente este concepto, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. +1 y porque no puedo votar mas. Puedes añadir un enlace al [wiki de openstreetmap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_Box) donde se explica el concepto :)

Comment: Voy a echarle un ojo a JTS. Aun así me guardo tu código :). Muchísimas gracias!! (A todos los que habéis colaborado, también!!!)

Comment: No entiendo cómo se obtiene un punto en un sistema de dos coordenadas (latitud longitud) con cuatro coordenadas relativas (NSEO) O___o

Comment: Gracias, @Pikoh.

Comment: En realidad con esas 4 coordenadas [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax] estás definiendo los límites de un polígono rectangular cerrado. En realidad tenemos las coordenadas de los 4 puntos. Héchale un ojo al código donde se crea el polígono @PaperdBirdMaster

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo entiendo que un rectángulo se puede definir con 4 coordenadas, no entiendo que se pueda definir con cuatro puntos cardinales pues las coordenadas definen puntos y los puntos cardinales definen dirección, así que estoy completamente perdido y perplejo. Le echaré un vistazo a lo que dices a ver si lo entiendo.

Comment: Ah vale, entiendo lo que dices. A mí también me confundió eso en la pregunta. Pero viendo los valores y leyendo lo comentarios, entiendo que son coordenadas (Las que definen esos dos vértices opuestos del rectángulo). Si fueran puntos cardinales bastaría saber un valor en la dirección del punto cardinal deseado para obtener un punto. (50 grados en la dirección Norte). Por eso llego a la conclusión de que lo que se tiene realmente es un Bounding Box. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Uhm, pues eso tmb me cuadra, un Geometry Bounding Box